# ASP.NET MVC Many-to-Many Relationship (Maintaining insertion order)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity, insertion

I've defined two tables in SQL: "Inquerito" and "Pergunta", and a third table "Inquerito_Pergunta" to make the many-to-many relationship. In that last table, the primary key is both the primary key of the Inquerito and the Pergunta.

I'am supposed to add as many as "Perguntas" as I want into an "Inquerito" instance. And, it's important to keep the insertion order, so when I'm showing it to the user it's shown in the same order. A "Pergunta" can also have multiple "Inquerito", but the order doesn't matter in that case.

I'm using MVC 4 Entity Framework and my Models are defined like this:

```
    public partial class Inquerito
    {
      public Inquerito()
      {
          this.Pergunta = new List<Pergunta>();
      }

      public System.Guid id { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Pergunta> Pergunta { get; set; }
    }


    public partial class Pergunta
    {
      public Pergunta()
      {
        this.Inquerito = new List<Inquerito>();
      }

      public System.Guid id { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Inquerito> Inquerito { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see I've already changed the default HashSet to a List.

To save all stuff to the database I do:

```
    inquerito.Pergunta.Add(pergunta);
    db.Pergunta.Add(pergunta);
    db.Inquerito.Add(inquerito);
```

The problem is the insertion order is lost.

After adding all "Pergunta" that I want I do:

```
        // Grava alterações e desconecta da base de dados.
        db.SaveChanges();

        Inquerito inquerito1 = db.Inquerito.Find(inquerito.id);
        if (inquerito1 != null)
        {
            foreach (Pergunta p in inquerito1.Pergunta.ToList())
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("__pergunta: " + p.descricao);
            }
        }

        db = new quest_geralEntities();

        inquerito1 = db.Inquerito.Find(inquerito.id);
        if (inquerito1 != null)
        {
            foreach (Pergunta p in inquerito1.Pergunta.ToList())
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("__pergunta: " + p.descricao);
            }
        }
```

So, the first time I print all the "Pergunta" linked to that "Inquerito" everything is shown in the right order (insertion order), but when I update the context, with: "new quest_geralEntities()" when I print it again the insertion order is completely lost.

I've been struggling with this problem for several hours now and I can't find a solution. I hope I've been clear enough to be helped.

Thanks.

Comment: How is entity framework (or your backing store) supposed to know the order in which your items should appear when you retrieve them back?

Comment: When you put it that way... I thought that the database would keep track of the List...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to maintain insertion order, I recommend using a field containing an int that increments.  You can add an int identity column without it being the primary key and use that column to sort on, maintaining your insertion order.

Comment: I added an int into the relationship class to keep track of the position. That actually worked very well, but now in the Entity Framework the "PerguntaInquerito" class became a Model, so I can no longer use, p.e.: inquerito.Pergunta.Add(p);

But, it worked, thanks.

Comment: If you consider it the answer, I would appreciate if you marked it as the answer.  You could possibly make the int identity column the primary key and let entity framework and sql server handle the values for that column.  You could still maintain your relationships with a a foreign key constraint and a unique constraint and I think you would be able to use ".Add(p)" again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the property type of your relation :

```
public virtual IList<Inquerito> Inquerito { get; set; }
public virtual IList<Pergunta> Pergunta { get; set; }
```

You'll need to regenerate the database schema. I'm not sure if it's working on EF, but in NHibernate, it works.

Hope it helps !